# GData causing an error message when running the profiler

Tags: objective-c, xcode, profiler, gdata, gdata-api

So, my dilemma here is pretty much the fact that I have GData included with static headers in my file per the instructions found here: http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/. Everything compiles correctly and such and I can run the Analyzer just fine. The minute I try to run the profiler to check for leaks, it hits the attached error The service placeholder compiler flag should be replaced by actual service specifications as seen below: 
[image]

I'm not %100 sure on what I need to do to make this an acceptable service.. or why it triggers this error. Implementing GData was already a not-so-fun walk in the park. (Thank you the guy who added his static tutorial in google's documentation.. lack of documentation). Does anyone know specifically what needs to be done and/or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#Removing_Unneeded_Code)...

> There is a conditional set in the static library target as a reminder
>   to developers to define the needed services. For your project, replace
>   or delete the definition
>
> -DGDATA_INCLUDE_nameServiceHere_SERVICE=1
>
> in the Other C Flags section of the static library target's Release
>   configuration.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I removed that definition in the GDataTouchStaticLib Target and wall. Thank you!